# How to set QPixmap to null

Tags: c++, qt, null, qt5, qpixmap

I have a function that receives reference to `QPixmap` as a parameter like so:

```
void myFunction(QPixmap &pixmap){
    //[...]
}
```

How can I set the pixmap to "null" so that `pixmap.isNull()` returns `true` after calling `myFunction()` on a pixmap that had loaded content in it?

Example:

```
//1. Create pixmap
QPixmap pixmap;
qDebug() << pixmap.isNull(); //true

//2. load image
pixmap.load("existing_image.png");
qDebug() << pixmap.isNull(); //false

//3. run myFunction on pixmap
myFunction(pixmap);
qDebug() << pixmap.isNull(); //true
```

Comment: I don't know qt much, but looking at the documentation, can't you simply do pixmap = QPixmap() ?

Comment: @eyllanesc reference to an object can be copy-assigned to. What's the problem? According to QPixmap documentation, isNull will be true whenever the QPixmap is null constructed.

Comment: @AlexG oops, excuse me, you're right, it's only necessary: `void myFunction(QPixmap &pixmap){ ...; pixmap = QPixmap();}`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One way would be to use the [swap()](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qpixmap.html#swap) method to replace the image data with a null `QPixmap`:

```
void myFunction(QPixmap &pixmap){
    pixmap.swap(QPixmap());
}
```

The documentation for `swap()` (linked above) states:

> Swaps pixmap other with this pixmap. This operation is very fast and
>   never fails.